# Setting default image before uploading new image in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I want to set a default image before i can upload any image from my gallery here is my code

```js
state = {
        user: {
            avatar : require('../assets/user.png')

        }
    }
    handlePickAvatar = async () => {

        UserPermission.getCamerPermission()
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes : ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect:[4,3]
        })
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, avatar: result.uri } });
        }
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.profile}>Profile</Text>
                <View style={styles.avatarPlaceholder} >
                    <Image source={{ uri: this.state.user.avatar }}  style={styles.avatar} />


                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePickAvatar}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Load Image</Text>                    
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

[The results should be like this the user image must be defaulted but i get the error :value for uri cannot be cast from double to string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddEIR.png)

is there any solution for this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
        user: {
            avatar : ''

        }
    }
```

and now you make a check

```
<Image source={!!this.state.user.avatar ? { uri: this.state.user.avatar } : require('../assets/user.png')
}  style={styles.avatar} />
```